# Combining different names in a database

Tags: python, regex, database, chess

I am studying a chess database with more than one million games. I am interested in identifying some characteristics of different players. The problem I have is that each single player appears with several identifications.

For example,

`"Carlsen, M."`, `"Carlsen, Ma"`, `"Carlsen, Magnus"` and `"Magnus Carlsen"` 
all correspond to player `"Magnus Carlsen"`.

Furthermore, there are other players which share Carlsen's last name, but have different names, such as `"Carlsen, Ingrid Oen"` and `"Carlsen, Jesper"`.

I need to identify all the different names in the database which correspond to each specific player and combine them. Is there any way to do that with Python?

Comment: You can try to create an `alias-generator` function that uses an input name, e.g., "Magnus Carlsen" and creates all these different combinations you provided above. Do this for all players, go through the database, see what is not picked up, make the generator more sophisticated and repeat. Since you can code in Python, use your skills; there is no magic solution here I am afraid

Comment: If this is a large chess database, you will definitely have ambiguities where the same identifier string is used for two different players.

Comment: Ev. Kounis That is indeed a solution, but unfortunately the database is huge (around 100000 players) so it wont be practical I'm affraid. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

@Ev.Kounis solution is simple and effective, I've used it myself successfully. Most of the time, we only care the top chess players. That's what I did:

- Created a simple function like @Ev.Jounis suggests
- I also scanned the player rating. For example, there were several "Carlsen" players in my database, but they wouldn't have FIDE rating over 2700.
- I also search the other player in the game. If I'm interested in Garry Kasparov, he wouldn't be playing a club game with a 1600 rated opponent.
- Get a better database. Chessgames and TWIC have better quality than Chessbase.

You could try regular expression, but it's unnecessary. There's a **simple** **pattern** how a player name would differ:

> "Carlsen, M" == "Magnus Carlsen"

This applies to other players in the database. Save regular expression until you really have to do it.